# Headlines links wont be created

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I'm currently busy with a ticketsystem. A headline will be displayed. When the headline has over 40 characters, the headline will be cut and the '...' will be added. Now, when I try to link the headlines to its messages, it won't create a link. I'm using Ajax to do this without a page refresh, but no links are being created, which means that the full ticket wont be openend. I've tried several things but I cant get it to work. I'm also not that familiar with it :')

**This is my piece of JS:**

```
//Show ticket
function showTicket(id) {
    $.ajax({url:"readTicket.php?ticket_id=" + id});
}
```

**This is the piece of code supposed to link the headlines:**

```
<?php echo '<a id="showTicketNow" onclick="showTicket('.$stt["ticket_id"].')">' ?>
<?php if(strlen($stt['subject']) > 40) $stt['subject'] = substr($stt['subject'], 0, 40).'...';
 echo $stt['subject'] ?>
<?php echo '</a>' ?>
```

**This is my readTicket.php**

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$ticket_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['ticket_id']);
$getTicketInfo = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_id = '$ticket_id' AND user_id = '$user_id'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getTicketInfo)) {
    $subject = $row['subject']; 
    $message = $row['message']; 
}
echo '<div class="showTicket display subject">'.stripslashes($subject).'</div>
      <div class="showTicket display message">'.stripslashes($message).'</div>';
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you want to delete the question, you can [do so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42297/229247) it if you like, but please don't "vandalize" it while it is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you were missing all of the syntax goodness.

```
echo'<a id="showTicketNow" onclick="showTicket('.$stt["ticket_id"].')">';
if(strlen($stt['subject']) > 40){
    $stt['subject'] = substr($stt['subject'], 0, 40).'...';
}
echo $stt['subject'];
echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify href attribute of <a> tag, something like this:

```
<?php echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showTicketNow" onclick="showTicket('.$stt["ticket_id"].')">' ?>
```

Comment: Tried that already, but since I'm using JS to control the link I removed the href ghehe.

Comment: javascript:void(0); in href will not force browser to (re)load anything, anyway - without href attribute <a> tag will not be rendered as link